# Combine array in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, array-merge

Hi This is my code and just not sure what to do

```
db.car3.aggregate([{$group:{_id:"$Manufacturer",Extras:{$push:"$Extras"}}}])
```

The result I got is

```
{_ID:"Fiat","Extra:[[Aircon,parking,GPS],[GPS,Parking Sensor, Pass]]"},
{_ID:"Toyota","Extra:[[ABS,Power Windows,GPS],[GPS,Auto Wiper, Pass]]"}
```

I not sure how would I combine those array together so at the end it being this

```
{_ID:"Fiat","Extra:[[Aircon,parking,GPS,Parking Sensor, Pass]]"},    
{_ID:"Toyota","Extra:[ABS,Power Windows,GPS,Auto Wiper, Pass]"}
```

Comment: Do you like to get an array or a nested array? I doubt the result comes from the code above (`Extras` does not match `Extra`, it is not a valid BSON anyway)

Comment: { $push: { <field1>: <value1>, ... } }

Answer (score 0):

You use the `$reduce` operator to combine each element in an array to a single value (in this case multiple arrays into a single array).

Just add this stage to your aggregation after the `$group` stage:

```
{ 
  $addFields: { 
      Extra: { 
          $reduce: { 
               input: "$Extra", 
               initialValue: [ ], 
               in: { $concatArrays : [ "$$value", "$$this" ]  } 
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: `$$value` and `$$this` are special variables used within the `$reduce` construct. `$$value` refers to the value being _accumulated_ (or reduced) to a single array, where it is initialized at `initialValue`. `$$this` refers to the current element of the array. The reduce function iterates thru the array (`$Extra`, in this case) and accumulates elements into a single array - that is what you see in the result. I think that is the expected result. See docs at [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/index.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `$extra` is already an array. So, before `$group` use `$unwind`.

Also, instead of `$push` use `$addToSet` to keep the fields unique in the array.

The updated query will look like:

```
db.car3.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind:"$Extras"
    },
    {
        $group:{
            _id:"$Manufacturer",
            Extras:{
                $addToSet:"$Extras"
            }
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

Hence, further merging is not required after this.

Output will be:

```
{_ID:"Fiat","Extra:[[Aircon,parking,GPS,Parking Sensor, Pass]]"},    
{_ID:"Toyota","Extra:[ABS,Power Windows,GPS,Auto Wiper, Pass]"}
```